# Printing alphabets advanced by n in Python

Tags: python, string

how can i write a python program to intake some alphabets in and print out (alphabets+n) in the output. Example

```
my_string = 'abc'
expected_output = 'cde' # n=2
```

One way I've thought is by using `str.maketrans`, and mapping the original input to (alphabets + n). Is there any other way?

PS: xyz should translate to abc

I've tried to write my own code as well for this, (apart from the infinitely better answers mentioned):

```
number = 2
prim =  """abc! fgdf """
final = prim.lower()
for x in final:
    if(x =="y"):
        print("a", end="")
    elif(x=="z"):
        print("b", end="")
    else:
        conv = ord(x)
        x = conv+number
        print(chr(x),end="")
```

Any comments on how to **not** convert special chars? thanks

Comment: What is your alphabet? Lower-case ASCII letters? Do you want it to wrap around?

Comment: yes, lowercase alphabets, but that's not the issue i can use .lower/upper. I want to print input alphabets advanced by n. not sure what you mean by "Do you want it to wrap around?"

Comment: what should `z` shift = 2 output? Also are all the characters valid ascii?

Comment: Do you want y and z to become a and b respectively?

Comment: yes, xyz, should translate to abc. That's the issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't care about wrapping around, you can just do:

```
def shiftString(string, number):
    return "".join(map(lambda x: chr(ord(x)+number),string))
```

If you do want to wrap around (think Caesar chiffre), you'll need to specify a start and an end of where the alphabet begins and ends:

```
def shiftString(string, number, start=97, num_of_symbols=26):
    return "".join(map(lambda x: chr(((ord(x)+number-start) %
           num_of_symbols)+start) if start <= ord(x) <= start+num_of_symbols
           else x,string))
```

That would, e.g., convert `abcxyz`, when given a shift of 2, into `cdezab`.

If you actually want to use it for "encryption", make sure to exclude non-alphabetic characters (like spaces etc.) from it.

**edit:** Shameless plug of my [Vignère tool in Python](https://github.com/L3viathan/vignere-explorer)

**edit2:** Now only converts in its range.

Comment: For this solution, is there a way it can handle blank spaces as well. It is currently replacing spaces by 'p'.

Comment: As I said, you will not want to replace anything outside this range. But give me a second

Comment: Ok, should only consider lowercase letters now (by default).

Answer (score 2):

How about something like

```
>>> my_string = "abc"
>>> n = 2
>>> "".join([ chr(ord(i) + n) for i in my_string])
'cde'
```

**Note** As mentioned in comments the question is bit vague about what to do when the edge cases are encoundered like `xyz`

---

**Edit** To take care of edge cases, you can write something like

```
>>> from string import ascii_lowercase
>>> lower = ascii_lowercase
>>> input = "xyz"
>>> "".join([ lower[(lower.index(i)+2)%26] for i in input ])
'zab'
>>> input = "abc"
>>> "".join([ lower[(lower.index(i)+2)%26] for i in input ])
'cde'
```

Comment: What happens with `xyz`?

Comment: @BhargavRao actually, it won't

Comment: @inspectorG4dget Op hasn't mentioed that the conversion should be cyclic. If that is required then this won't work

Comment: @vaultah Yeah. Forgot that this case is diff. My bad! Anyway  the OP should change the variable name from `input` to something else as `input` is a built-in func

Comment: @inspectorG4dget Untidy solution using list. Am not sure of pythonic way of doing this :/

Answer (score 0):

I've made the following change to the code:

```
number = 2
prim =  """Special() ops() chars!!"""
final = prim.lower()
for x in final:
    if(x =="y"):
        print("a", end="")
    elif(x=="z"):
        print("b", end="")
    elif (ord(x) in range(97, 124)):
        conv = ord(x)
        x = conv+number
        print(chr(x),end="")
    else:
        print(x, end="")

**Output**: urgekcn() qru() ejctu!!
```

Answer (score 0):

```
test_data = (('abz', 2), ('abc', 3), ('aek', 26), ('abcd', 25))
# translate every character
def shiftstr(s, k):
    if not (isinstance(s, str) and isinstance(k, int) and k >=0):
        return s
    a = ord('a')
    return ''.join([chr(a+((ord(c)-a+k)%26)) for c in s])

for s, k in test_data:
    print(shiftstr(s, k))
print('----')

# translate at most 26 characters, rest look up dictionary at O(1)
def shiftstr(s, k):
    if not (isinstance(s, str) and isinstance(k, int) and k >=0):
        return s
    a = ord('a')
    d = {}
    l = []
    for c in s:
        v = d.get(c)
        if v is None:
            v = chr(a+((ord(c)-a+k)%26))
            d[c] = v
        l.append(v)
    return ''.join(l)

for s, k in test_data:
    print(shiftstr(s, k))
```

```
 Testing shiftstr_test.py (above code):
 $ python3 shiftstr_test.py 
 cdb
 def
 aek
 zabc
----
cdb
def
aek
zabc

It covers wrapping.
```